# POSTGIS TopologyException: side location conflict

Tags: sql, postgresql, polygon, postgis, intersect

I'm trying to execute a simple st_intersects query:

```
select st_intersects('MULTIPOLYGON(((1 5,4 8,7 5,4 2,1 5)),((5 5,8 8,11 5,8 2,5 5)))','POLYGON((3 4.5,3 5,4 5,4 4,3 4.5))');
```

which crush the console and returns the following error:

> Error: GEOSIntersects: TopologyException: side location conflict at: 6 4

Which is completely odd because the following query works:

```
select st_intersects('MULTIPOLYGON(((1 5,4 8,7 5,4 2,1 5)),((5 5,8 8,11 5,8 2,5 5)))','POLYGON((3 4,3 5,4 5,4 4,3 4))');
```

The only difference between the two is the 4 / 4.5 in the last polygon..

I use POSTGIS version 2.2.1
what am i missing here?

Answer (score 14):

I found a relevant solution to my problem.

```
select st_intersects(st_buffer('MULTIPOLYGON(((1 5,4 8,7 5,4 2,1 5)),((5 5,8 8,11 5,8 2,5 5)))',0),'POLYGON((3 4.5,3 5,4 5,4 4,3 4.5))');
```

When i added the `st_buffer` it merge the two polygons of the multipolygon to one and solved the issue.

Comment: Thank you. You've saved me lots of hours of searching!

Comment: This should be marked as the accepted answer so it floats to the top.

Answer (score 6):

you can check that the MultiPolygon geometry in your query is not a valid MultiPolygon:

```
=> select st_isvalid(
    st_geomfromtext(
        'MULTIPOLYGON(((1 5,4 8,7 5,4 2,1 5)),((5 5,8 8,11 5,8 2,5 5)))'
));
NOTICE:  Self-intersection at or near point 6 6
 st_isvalid
------------
 f
(1 row)
```

the reason for this is that the Polygon `(5 5,8 8,11 5,8 2,5 5)` defining the "hole" (inner ring) intersects the outer ring `(1 5,4 8,7 5,4 2,1 5)`.

It would be either necessary to fix the input manually, or one can use `ST_MakeValid` to do the job (it automatically detects and handles the overlapping parts):

```
=> select st_intersects(
    st_makevalid(
        'MULTIPOLYGON(((1 5,4 8,7 5,4 2,1 5)),((5 5,8 8,11 5,8 2,5 5)))'
    ),
    'POLYGON((3 4.5,3 5,4 5,4 4,3 4.5))'
);
 st_intersects 
---------------
 t
(1 row)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but it still doesn't explain why the second polygon intersect doesn't return any error

Answer (score 0):

I tried to compare a polygon and a collection of small polygons with ST_CoveredBy. I tried to collect my small polygons with `ST_collect` and got the same error.
I validated them with `st_IsValid`, turned `ST_collect(geom_1,geom_2...) >> ST_Union()` and it worked.